# Customize itemize environment

Tags: indentation, itemize

Say

```
\documentclass[french,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[french]{babel} \usepackage{kpfonts} \usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex} \setlength{\parindent}{0em} \clubpenalty = 10000 \widowpenalty = 10000

  \usepackage{graphicx,bm,url, amsfonts, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace,mathrsfs,marvosym,wasysym,amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{caption} \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} \usepackage{epstopdf}


\usepackage{enumitem} \setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=1pt,topsep=1pt} %\setlist[description]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=1pt,topsep=1pt} \setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=1pt,topsep=1pt}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true,    linkcolor=red,  urlcolor=blue,  pdftitle={article},     pdfauthor={DSA}]{hyperref}   \usepackage{geometry}  \geometry{  a4paper,  total={170mm,257mm},  left=20mm,  top=20mm,  }   \providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Mots clés ---}} #1}

\providecommand{\thematic}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Thématique ---}} #1}

\usepackage{authblk}

\newcommand{\M}{{\it Mathematica}}


\begin{document}

\title{BlaBlaBla} \author[,1]{Dimitrios\thanks{\texttt{\url{dimitrios.@X.fr}}}} %\author[,1]{Panos\thanks{ \texttt{\url{panos@Y.fr}}}} %\author[,1]{Thanos\thanks{Corresponding author:  %\texttt{\url{thanos@Z.fr}}}} \affil[1]{Université de nulle parte, Terre, Galaxie}

\date{}

\clearpage\maketitle \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{itemize}\setlength\itemsep{1em} \item \textbf{1993-1996:}  \blindtext \item  {\bf 1997-2002:}  \blindtext \item \textbf{2003-2015:} \blindtext

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

This gives

[image]

I want to modify the output so the years appear on the left and each text entry is indented to the right like the effect that we see in CVs. To be clear (I hope!) see the following picture.

[image]

I am wondering also how we can achieve the vertical line separation.

Comment: Don't use `\bf`, it is depreciated

Comment: @DG' \textbf instead?

Comment: Yes or `\bfseries`

Comment: @DG' Thanks a lot! One more question please. Is it clear what I am asking or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather use a `description` environment, patching the `\descriptionlabel` command:

```
\documentclass[french,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage{kpfonts}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{ a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm, showframe}
 \usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex} \setlength{\parindent}{0em} \clubpenalty = 10000 \widowpenalty = 10000

 \usepackage{graphicx,bm,url, amsfonts, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace,mathrsfs,marvosym,wasysym,amsmath, amssymb}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\descriptionlabel}{#1}{---\enspace#1 :}{}{}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle={article}, pdfauthor={DSA}]{hyperref} 
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Mots clés ---}} #1}

\providecommand{\thematic}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Thématique ---}} #1}

\usepackage{authblk}

\newcommand{\M}{{\it Mathematica}}

\begin{document}

\title{BlaBlaBla} \author[,1]{Dimitrios\thanks{\texttt{\url{dimitrios.@X.fr}}}} %

\date{}

\clearpage\maketitle \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{description}[itemsep=1em, leftmargin=80pt]
\item[1993-1996] \blindtext
\item[1997-2002] \blindtext
\item[2003-2015] \blindtext
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

see, if the following solution is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[french,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,  total={170mm,257mm},  left=20mm,  top=20mm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\clubpenalty = 10000 \widowpenalty = 10000

\usepackage{graphicx,bm,url, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace,mathrsfs,marvosym,wasysym,amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=red,
            urlcolor=blue,
            pdftitle={article},
            pdfauthor={DSA}]{hyperref}

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Mots clés ---}} #1}
\providecommand{\thematic}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Thématique ---}} #1}

\newcommand{\M}{\textit{Mathematica}}


\begin{document}
\title{BlaBlaBla}
\author[,1]{Dimitrios\thanks{\url{dimitrios.@X.fr}}}

\date{}
\clearpage\maketitle \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{description}[font=\textendash\,\bfseries,
                    leftmargin=27mm,
                    style=nextline]
\item[1993-1996:] \blindtext
\item[1997-2002:] \blindtext
\item[2003-2015:] \blindtext
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is very nice! Thanks a lot. Can we add also a vertical line between the "two columns"?

Comment: for vertical line: there are not two columns. vertical line from start of list to end of list is (almost) impossible to add.  if you like to have this, ask new question. it may happen that someone know how to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot in any case! I don't know which answer to choose! Both give the desired output.